# setting a timer in android based on a date in database

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am new to android. I have an application which needs to show a data stored in database (which is a time value, example 40 hours) in a textview.

I want to count down the value from 40 (in my case) to zero and an alarm should start when it hits zero.

[image: need to show countdown like image]

Comment: Cant understand what you have asked..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @hardikjoshi .my app is  about setting a time for study.that time is in the form of hours(eg,40 hours) which is stored in database.I should display that time value in a textView in a count down timer starting from 40 to downwards.When it hit zero an alarm should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just convert remaining time in second(get hour value from db and convert it into second, in my case i am getting time in seconds )

```
public class CountDownActivity extends Activity {

    int time,initStart,startPointTime,hh,mm,ss,millis;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtMinute;
    TextView txtHour;
    TextView txtDay;
    Handler handler;
    long seconds =40*60*60;
    Runnable updater;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    txtSecond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cntSecond);
            txtMinute=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cntMinute);
            txtHour=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cntHour);
            txtDay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cntDay);

                    handler= new Handler();
            initStart = (int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

             updater = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    int sec,minute,hour,day;
                    long  diff = seconds;
                    System.out.println(diff);
                    if (diff >= 1) {
                        sec =  (int) (diff%60);
                    } else {
                        sec=00;
                    }
                    txtSecond.setText("" +sec);
                    diff = diff/60;
                    System.out.println(diff);
                    if (diff >= 1) {
                        minute =  (int) (diff%60);
                    } else {
                        minute=00;
                    }
                    txtMinute.setText("" +minute);
                    diff = diff/60;
                    if (diff >= 1) {
                        hour =  (int) (diff%24);
                    } else {hour = 00; }
                    txtHour.setText("" +hour);
                    diff = diff/24;
                    if (diff >= 1) {
                        day =  (int) diff;
                    } else { day =00; }
                    txtDay.setText("" +day);
                    seconds=seconds-1;


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };

            handler.post(updater);
}

> //and don't forget to removeCallback on destroy

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
    }
}
```

Comment: may i know from where did variable seconds get the value

Comment: i have tried your code.but its not working

Comment: please, let me know what you get?, error or wrong result etc,please print value of seconds and check is it right or not? if you get right seconds then it should work.

Comment: @ParkerI have assigned the value for "diff" as  
     int diff = (int)t*60*60; since "t" is in hours and is stored in database.I dont understand the statement  "seconds=seconds-1;" in your prpgram and how i can implement in my program

Comment: what does this statement means??? long  diff = seconds;.i dont understand what is the variable seconds stands for.I thought variable means for the total time (in my case 40 hours)in seconds

Comment: @AnazA please check code I've Edited

Comment: its still not displaying correctly.

Comment: certain values are coming(that are not correct),but atlast a value like 0:53:4 is coming in emulater.(i am not displaying day,i need only hour,min and second).

Comment: I will send you the screenshots and code if you give me your e mail id.

Comment: @AnazA send me your code i ll check and update you, my id is **  mobi.parker@gmail.com **

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CountDownTimer` for counting down the value as follows:

```
  final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(600000, 1000); //add your time

 ...
   public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer
    {

        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            Log.i("debug","Timer Completed");

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {

            tv.setText("Timer : " + (millisUntilFinished/60000) + " " + "minutes remaining.");
        }

  }
```

For the alarm part you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.mikesir87.io/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/) for the same.

Hope it helps!